# Keep only capitalised words and remove spaces in between

Tags: r, regex

I have the following character vector of elements that include individual's full names.

```
strings <- c("Michelle Jane Smith", "Elise Alice Smith", "Ronald James Smith", "Thomas John Smith")
```

I now wish to extract each capital letter, removing the spaces in between. This would give initials. My anticipated output would be:

```
output <- c("MJS", "EAS", "RJS", "TJS")
```

Is this please possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `str_extract_all` command of `stringr` package, you can extract the characters that match the pattern for uppercase letters (`"[A-Z]+"`) and paste them together.

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_extract_all(string = strings, pattern = "[A-Z]+"),
        function(a) paste(a, collapse = ""))
#[1] "MJS" "EAS" "RJS" "TJS"
```

Or instead of looking for uppercase characters, you could just extract the first character of each word in `strings`

```
sapply(strsplit(x = strings, split = " "), function(a)
    paste(substr(x = a, start = 1, stop = 1), collapse = ""))
#[1] "MJS" "EAS" "RJS" "TJS"
```

Answer (score 2):

how about a `gsub`

```
gsub("[a-z]| ", "", strings)
[1] "MJS" "EAS" "RJS" "TJS"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `gsub`:

```
gsub("[a-z ]", "", strings)
```

Answer (score 2):

Or using capture groups

```
gsub("([A-Z]+)[a-z ]+", "\\1", strings)
#[1] "MJS" "EAS" "RJS" "TJS"
```

Comment: How can I learn about the tricks of strings? Would love to play with them the way you do. Thank you

Comment: @Onyambu  As far as I am concerned, it is the practice.  If I find some interesting approach from somebody, I will check it out.  Sometimes, there won't be much clarification.  It makes it interesting to break into simple pieces and check the behavior